# Почему в этой функции, контекст не выполняется?

Tags: jquery

```
function clearColor() {
    var labe = $("#label_text")
    $("#head").add("#foot").hover(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "color": "rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.47)",
            "text-shadow": "white 0px 0px 0px"
        })
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
            "color": "rgb(219, 133, 251)",
            "text-shadow": "black 2px 2px 4px"
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: this указывает не туда или что?

Comment: head add foot...интересно получается, но уточните вопрос

Comment: К голове добавим ножек, получился... не рабочет. =D  
(на правах оффтопа)

Answer (score 1):

попробуй перед #foot дописать имя тега

Answer (score 0):

А у меня работает контекст [смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/LeD4eG/8vUG4/).
НЕ забывайте про точки с запятыми. они **ВАЖНЫ**

Comment: кстати да, лучше написать $("#head, #foot")

Comment: да, конечно, лучше так, но не я автор этого кода.

Comment: что-то я тупанул, увидел "НЕ забывайте про точки с запятыми" и подумал что ты про это имел ввиду